# Html mail form doesn't send mail

Tags: html, forms, email

im having some problems with this form:

```
<form action="mailto:mymail@mail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain>
    <div class="field half first">
        <label for="fname">Pénom</label>
        <input name="fname" id="fname" type="text" placeholder="Veuillez insérer votre prénom" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field half first">
        <label for="name">Nom</label>
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Veuillez insérer votre nom" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field half first">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Veuillez insérer votre email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field half first">
        <label for="phone">Téléphone (portable)</label>
        <input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Veuillez insérer votre téléphone portable" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field half first">
        <label for="dept">Department</label>
        <div class="select-wrapper">
            <select name="dept" id="dept">
                <option value="1">Maintenance</option>
                <option value="1">Administration</option>
                <option value="1">Ressources humaines</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="6" placeholder="Veuillez insérer votre message, notre équipe sera ravie de vous répondre au plus vite !" required/>
    </div>
    <ul class="actions align-center">
        <li>
            <input value="Envoyer ;)" class="button special" type="submit">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

It just DOESNT send mails, i have tried many different methods but it stills not working. can someone help me? im just starting at this.

Comment: The user needs a mail program which is opened when submit is clicked. The browser won't just send a mail.

Comment: Can you dévellop a little bit more pls? as i said, im new at this so, if u could help me, i'd be glad :)

Comment: When I tried out the code it worked perfectly well (which means it opened my mail program with a new mail). I just wanted to be sure that you have a mail program to send the mail.

Comment: If you can use PHP you can try to send a mail from the server after posting the form to it. This doesn't require your user to send a mail himself.

Comment: @KevinDias, Your question is unclear. Do you want to send mail after clicked on submit button? If Yes, then to whom you want to send mail? User? or Admin?. You have to use Server side language like PHP

Comment: Well, im trying to create a website where clients can send me mails for informations etc..

Comment: @KevinDias You could try writing a server-side PHP script that automatically sends a mail to you when your formular is submittet. You have to change your form's action to the PHP script then.

Comment: `mailto:` is most often used in links, not forms. It's meant to open the client's default email program (e.g. Gmail, Thunderbird, Outlook, etc.) and requires them to continue the process of sending an email. If you want a real form to submit an email automatically then you'll need to use a server side script in a language like PHP